# Ajax Populated Dropdown Taking Two Clicks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My web page is an internal DB Move Tool for my company.  I have a section for source and for target.

I have radio buttons for host and port, and a dropdown for database name.  When host and port are set, I have a click event capture on the dropdown that sends an ajax request to a php page that queries for the databases on that instance and populates the dropdown options(this is for the target dropdown):

```
    $("#targetDrop").one("click",function() {
    ajaxTarget();
     });


function ajaxTarget() {
    $.ajax({
        url: './dbLookup.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            host: $("#targetHost:checked").val(),
            port: $("#targetPort:checked").val()
        }
    })
        .done(function(result) {
            console.log("Setting Result");
            for (i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                $("#targetDrop").append("<option name=\"targetDB\" value=\"" + result[i] + "\">" + result[i] + "</option>");
            }
        })
        .fail(errorFn)
        .always(function (data,textStatus,jqXHR){
            console.log("The request is complete!")
        });
```

My problem, is that you have to click the dropdown once (nothing shows), deselect it, and then click it again to see the populated values.  It makes sense, seeing as its taking the click to generate the data, so I need to reselect the dropdown to see the new data.

Is there a way of making this all happen on the first click?

Thanks!

Comment: In first line of your code replace `$("#targetDrop").one("click",function()` with `$("#targetDrop").on("click",function()`

Comment: That doesn't help with this problem.  I had used that function before, but if I kept clicking the dropdown it would append on to the end of the list and thus duplicate the results.

Comment: But if you use `one()` then only single time you can change dropdown.

Comment: I think you want "change", not "one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another more effective way of achieving this:

```
$("#targetHost, #targetPort").change(function () {
    if ($.trim($("#targetHost:checked").val()) != "" && $.trim($("#targetPort:checked").val()) != "") {
        dbLookUp();
    }
});

function dbLookUp() {
    var data = {
            host: $("#targetHost:checked").val(),
            port: $("#targetPort:checked").val()
        }
    $.ajax({
        url: './dbLookup.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
    }).done(function(response) {
        var opts = '<option value="">Choose Database...</option>';
        $.each(response, function(index, data) {
            opts += '<option name="targetDB" value="' + data + '">' + data + '</option>';
        });
        $("#targetDrop").html(opts);
    }).fail(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}

dbLookUp(); // Add this line if you have default selection for host and port
            // and you want to load the DB list as soon as the page loads up.
```

In this way you don't have to click on the dropdown to get it loaded... As soon as you select the host and port it will load up the doropdown. You can even load the db list on first page load.

Hope this helps.

Comment: just did that :) sorry, new to the site.